# Need of interfaces in c#

Tags: c#, interface

What is need of interfaces in c# ? as we are writing abstract method in interfaces. instead of that we can directly implement those methods in class.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you asking? How to use an interface?

Comment: what is need of interface ? you can directly write method in class

Comment: The interface can serve as a mandatory base for derived classes like abstract classes, but they are more general in that a derived class can implement _several_ interfaces.

Answer (score 8):

Interfaces don't support implementation, so you cannot supply any default implementations as you can with abstract classes. Additionally, interfaces are not restricted to hierarchies, so they are more flexible than abstract classes.

Comment: +1. For someone *finally* pointing out: *interfaces are not restricted to hierarchies*

Answer (score 6):

You do not *need* to use interfaces in C#.  They are useful and appropriate in *some* circumstances, but not in *all* circumstances.  A handy rule of thumb that I use is that if, in your project, you only have one class that implements an interface, you do not need that interface.

Note:  one possible counter to this rule of thumb is that you may need to write a second implementing class in the future, which may justify the use of the interface.  I do not necessarily agree, as I think a considerable amount of time in programming is wasted anticipating future scenarios which never materialize.

Comment: What about unit testing?  I normally use interfaces because I create a second implementation as a stub or mock for testing.  Making your rule of thumb mean you should always use interfaces.

Comment: But when you are writing unit tests, you almost always need to mock/stub out the class if it is a dependency of another class.  By doing that, you are automatically creating a second implementation of the interface in your test project.  Because of this, I find that I create interfaces more often than not for my classes in order to write testable, decoupled code.

Comment: @DotNetWill and Brian Genisio: I do not see how what you wrote is in any way contrary to what I wrote in my answer. If you choose to mock/stub a class for unit testing, then you will have more than one class that implements an interface, and you thus need to use an interface. If you do not mock/stub a class for unit testing, and you have only one implementation of that class in your project, then you do not need an interface. Am I missing something in your comments? Are you saying that *every class* in *every project* should implement an interface? That seems an overly strong assertion.

Comment: a counter example would be .net remoting, where you have one class that provides the implementation and the interface you serve to the client to use the object.

Comment: @Blindy: that's a legitimate exception to my rule of thumb, but that's why I called it a "rule of thumb" rather than an "inviolable law of the universe". :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read up on [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism).

Comment: Wikipedia eh? ;-) Maybe this link is helpful too (and more specific): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For myself, I find a lot of use out of interfaces when I have similar objects but completely different implementations of the same methods.

Additionally, you can implement multiple interfaces but inherit only one abstract class. I find this very useful because my business objects have a better representation.

When writing any N-Tiered application which separates out business logic from the presentation I think you will start to find many uses for interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Interface is needed exactly as described in books: to define a contract between components. They are one of the best ways to expose certain functionality to other modules while preserving encapsulation.

For example:

1) try, without an interface, to expose some piece of functionality implemented in assembly 'A', to assembly 'B', with no actual implementation visible to assembly 'A'.

2) Even worse - if we consider .NET remoting scenarios, where the server must expose certain 
functionality to the client, while the functionality is implemented and hosted on the server side. In this case an assembly is published to a client, where interfaces for the server-hosted classes are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Think of Interfaces as contracts.

You create a contract that a class must follow. For example, if our Dog object must have a Walk method, it's defining class *must* implement this method.

In order to force every dog class (inherited or not) to implement this method, you must make them adhere to a contract i.e assign an interface which specifies that method.

An interface is a construct that enforces particular classes to follow strict rules of implementation.

The reason for this is that you end up with Dog objects (inherited or not) that now, by default, have a Walk method. This means you can pass these objects as parameters, safe in the knowledge that you can call the Walk method on any Dog class (inherited or not) and it will deffinately be implemented.

Comment: @Gary but an abstract class is also a contract :)

Comment: True, but that doesn't affect my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write testable code, you will usually need to employ interfaces.  When unit testing, you may have ClassA which depends upon ClassB which Depends upon ClassC etc, but you only want to test ClassA.  You certainly don't want to create a ClassC to pass to a ClassB just to instantiate ClassA.

In that case, you make ClassA depend upon IClassB (or some more generic name, most likely that does not imply anything about the ClassB implementation) and mock out IClassB in your tests.

It is all about dependency management for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need interfaces when you want to think of a disparate set of classes as all being the same type of object.  Say, for example, you have a set of classes that all read their configuration from a file.  One way to handle this is to have all the classes implement the appropriate methods to read a configuration  from a file.  The trouble with this is that then any code that uses those classes and wants to configure them needs to know about all the different classes so that it can use the methods on them.

Another way is to have them all derive from a single base class.  That way any code using the classes need only know about the base class -- it can treat any of the derived classes as the base class and use those methods defined in the base class to do the configuration.  This isn't so bad, but it has the major drawback -- since C# doesn't support multiple inheritance -- of limiting your inheritance chain.  If you want to be able to have the same sort of ability for some of the classes, but not all of them for a different set of behavior, you're stuck implementing it for all of them anyway.  Not good.

The last way is to use interfaces to define the behavior.  Any class wanting to implement the behavior need only implement the interface.  Any class wanting to use the behavior need only know about the interface and can then use any class that implements it.  Classes can implement any interface or even multiple interfaces so you have granular "allocation" of behavior among classes.  You can still use base classes and inheritance hierarchies to provide the main behavior of a class in a shared way, but the class is also free to implement other interfaces to give itself more behavior and still retain the convenience of classes that use it to know only about the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces allow implementers to use their own base class. With abstract classes, implementers are forced to use the given base class to implement the interface even if it actually makes more sense for the implementer to use a project-specific base class.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are used to define the behaviour/properties of classes without specifying the implementation. If you begin thinking about classes as fulfilling roles rather than just being a bundle of methods and properties then you can begin assigning multiple roles to classes using interfaces - which is not possible using straight inheritance in C# as you can only inherit from a single class. By making clients of the classes depend on the interfaces (roles) rather than the class itself your code will be more loosely coupled and probably better designed.

Another benefit of this is if you are writing unit tests they are more likely to be focussed on behaviour rather than state. Coding against interfaces makes it very easy to make mock/stub implementations for this type of testing.

Not everything will need interfaces - but most things with behaviour probably (i.e. more than just a bundle of data) should have them IMHO as you'll always have two implementations: a real one in your application and one or more fake ones in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Interface is a contract that defines the signature of the functionality. So if a class is implementing
a interface it says to the outer world, that it provides specific behavior.

Example if a class is
implementing ‘Idisposable’ interface that means it has a functionality to release unmanaged
resources. Now external objects using this class know that it has contract by which it can dispose
unused unmanaged objects.

Answer (score 0):

As presented by GoF 1st principle: Program to an interface not an implementation.

This helps in many ways. It's easier to change the implementation, it's easier to make the code testable and so on...

Hopes this helps.