# Was the "interface" keyword removed from Dart?

Tags: class, interface, dart, abstract, definition

Just to be sure, has Dart removed explicitly defining an `interface` now in favor of implicitly defining it via `abstract`?

I see it mentioned in [Dart and Interface Segregation Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791286/dart-and-interface-segregation-principle), however I'm also finding a lot of content still referencing the explicit definition, such as [When to use interfaces in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502649/when-to-use-interfaces-in-dart)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes. The interface keyword was removed from Dart. Instead all classes have [implicit interfaces](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#implicit-interfaces). So if you want to define an interface you can use an abstract class instead.

See this [blog post](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/proposal-to-eliminate-interface.html) from 2012 about eliminating the interface keyword.

Answer (score 6):

Please note that the accepted answer is no longer true.

Dart 3 has re-introduced the `interface` keyword. See here: https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#interface

The semantic of this differs from what you might expect from your background in other languages like Java: In Dart, this is only a class modifier that ensures that code in other files (= "libraries" in Dart) can not extend this class but must implement it completely (or be abstract).

To get Java-like "pure" interfaces, use `abstract interface`

Answer (score 1):

Using interface modifier allows the class to be used in an implements clause, but prevents it from being used in extends.

It was reintroduced but I think in different context. You can checkout below link for more details.

[Interface Modifier Usecase](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers-for-apis#the-interface-modifier)