# Casting class object to interface C#

Tags: c#, interface, implements

I'm wondering what opportunities casting class object to interface that it implements from gives? For example:

```
     public interface IOwner
        {
            int Owner { get; set; }
        }

      public interface IArmy
        {
            Army Army { get; set; }
        }

      public interface ITreasure
        {
            Treasure Treasure { get; set; }
        }

      public class Creep : IOwner, IArmy, ITreasure
       {
        public int Owner { get; set; }
        public Army Army { get; set; }
        public Treasure Treasure { get; set; }   
       }
```

and class that works with it:

```
public static class Interaction

{
    public static void Make(Player player, object mapObject)
    {
        if (mapObject is IArmy)
            if (player.CanBeat(((IArmy)mapObject).Army))
            {
                if (mapObject is IOwner)
                    ((IOwner)mapObject).Owner = player.Id;
                if (mapObject is ITreasure)
                    player.Consume(((ITreasure)mapObject).Treasure);
            }
```

So now when I call this line: `(player.CanBeat(((IArmy)mapObject).Army))` do I get access to Army field from mapObject class? It's obviously not interface's field since we can't work with them. Thanks in advice!

Comment: Are asking what's the point of interfaces?

Comment: Yes,   That's how inheritance and dynamic casting works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should one use interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686174/when-should-one-use-interfaces)

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cast `mapObject` to `IArmy` interface it still stays `mapObject` class (Creep) on the inside but you can only call what is implied by `IArmy` interface.

If you ask why and how it can be used: you can create another class that implements `IArmy` interface and when you cast it to `IArmy` you can process it the same way as the other classes that implement it.