# How would I make this program work as an OOP program so I can use my array everywhere in my code?

Tags: vb.net, oop

I am trying to make this an OOP program. I wanted to use constructors so I could use the array in other classes through inheritance. I would make the actual array in the MakeArray class. The test class is an example of a class I would use the array in.

```
Class superClass
        Protected array1D() As String
        Protected array2D(,) As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal array() As String)
            array1D = array
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal array(,) As String)
            array2D = array
        End Sub

        Public Sub New()
            'intialise without a course
        End Sub
    End Class

    Class MakeArray
        Inherits superClass

        Function Import1DArray() As Array
            Dim fileReader As New StreamReader("1Darray.txt")
            Dim lineFromFile As String = fileReader.ReadLine()
            Dim counter As Integer = 0
            Do
                ReDim Preserve array1D(counter)
                array1D(counter) = lineFromFile
                lineFromFile = fileReader.ReadLine()
                counter = counter + 1
            Loop Until lineFromFile = ""

            Return array1D
        End Function
    End Class

    Class test
        Inherits superClass

        Sub test()
            For i = 0 To 2 Step 1
                Console.WriteLine(array1D(i))
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class
```

I am quite new to OOP, so I'm not 100% sure about how it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Class inheritance is not the way here, `Interface` implementation is more suitable here. for example, if you have`Animal` super class (base class in .net) that you can write a derived class `Tiger` or `Dog` or `Cat` etc... because thay are all animal and share properties/fields that all animals has. MakeArray is not SuperClass lige Tiger is Animal

Comment: I learnt a bit about Interfaces, but never got a solid understanding. I learnt about abstract classes and I heard they are similar? How would it work? Thanks!

Comment: When I first started programming, using interfaces was very confusing to me to. here is a nice starting point to explore (its C# but the principles are the same in VB.NET): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686174/when-should-one-use-interfaces. their is vast of information for this topic.

Comment: I could make the program using both inheritance and interface possibly? It seems a lot easier with the use of interfaces, but how could I use inheritance for it? I wanted to get an idea of all the basics of OOP. Thanks!

Comment: Technically you can do this with Inheritance, but it will harm the understanding of this topic. and yes VB.NET allows you to inherit class (only one) and implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: Ah ok. The thing is, I just can't see how I could use inheritance here, but if its possible then is there a simple change to the program I have to make to make it work? Thanks!